# I want to set dynamic theme, so how to get application's theme colorPrimary,colorAccent value in pre-lollipop devices for android?

Tags: android, android-theme, android-4.4-kitkat

For API>=21 we get the colorPrimary,colorAccent values using **"?attr/colorPrimary"** or **"?colorPrimary"**. But it won't works on pre-lollipop devices. It shows some error like below. Thanks in advance.

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to
>   color: type=0x2
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:327)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.inflate(GradientDrawable.java:970)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
>                                                                                     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2148)
>                                                                                     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
>                                                                                     at android.view.View.(View.java:3579) 
>                                                                                     at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:642) 
>                                                                                     at android.widget.Button.(Button.java:107) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:71) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.(AppCompatButton.java:67) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081) 
>                                                                                     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
>                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
>                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)

Answer (score 0):

`colorPrimary` was added with the `Material Design` update in Android 5.0. It doesn't exist on devices that run Android < 5.0.

Comment: Then how can I change to dynamic theme based on button click on pre-lollipo devices?

Answer (score 0):

As `@Iulian Popescu` said `colorPrimary` proposed above lollipop version

so Instead of **"?attr/colorPrimary" or "?colorPrimary"**  use to reference from color.xml like below

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

or set color property directly "#RGB" value like

```
android:background="#000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color defined in your colors.xml file : `@color/colorPrimary`